# Formulated a curious conjecture involving all the primes $\geq 5$ being specially represented only with primes $2$ and $3$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

If $p$ is a prime $\geq 5$ we have:

$5=2+3$

$7=2^2+3$

$11=3^2+2$

$13=3^2+2^2$

$17=3^2+2^3$

$19=3^3-2^3$

$23=3^3-2^2$

$29=3^3+2$

$31=3^3+2^2$

$37=3^3+2^3+2$

$41=3^3+3^2+3+2$

$43=3^3+2^4$

$47=3^4-2^5-2$

$53=3^4-2^5+2^2$
...

I didn´t go beyond $53$ but I would like to formulate this curious conjecture:

> For every prime $p \geq 5$ there exist numbers $i_1,...,i_{m(p)}$ and $j_1,...,j_{n(p)}$ and $k_1,...,k_{m(p)}$ and $l_1,...,l_{n(p)}$ and $a_1,...,a_{m(p)}$ and $b_1,...,b_{n(p)}$ such that we have $$p= \sum_{r=1}^{m(p)}(-1)^{i_r} 2^{k_r}a_{r}+\sum_{s=1}^{n(p)}(-1)^{j_s}3^{l_s}b_{s}$$
>
> and $i_1,...,i_{m(p)},j_1,...,j_{n(p)} \in \{1,2\}$ and $a_1,...,a_{m(p)},b_1,...,b_{n(p)} \in \{0,1\}$ and $k_1 \cdot ... \cdot k_{m(p)} \neq 0$ and $l_1 \cdot ... \cdot l_{n(p)} \neq 0$ and the term $3-2=1$ is absent and the term $3^2-2^3=1$ is absent.

Is this true?

(Of course, we also want that both $\sum_{r=1}^{m(p)}(-1)^{i_r} 2^{k_r}a_{r}$ and  $\sum_{s=1}^{n(p)}(-1)^{j_s}3^{l_s}b_{s}$ to be $\neq 0$ for this to make much sense and be curious).

Comment: Note: $53 \ne 2^6-3^2$.

Comment: @paw88789 Well, for very small values of $2$,...

Comment: @Deepak hahaha :D

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/354839/expressing-primes-in-a-special-way-with-just-powers-of-2-and-3

Answer (score 8):

Yes, express the primes in binary. It is well known that any natural number (and thus any prime) can be expressed as the sum of powers of $2$. For example:

$$79=64+8+4+2+1$$ $$79=2^6+2^3+2^2+2^1+2^0$$

This solves the problem.

If you do not allow $2^0$, then first remove $3$ from the prime. This ensures that the difference is even (since primes are odd) . We will then not require $2^0$.

$$79-3=2^6+2^3+2^2 $$ $$ 79=2^6+2^3+2^2+3$$

Comment: I did not mention before an edit that such trivialites are excluded.

Comment: Wait, I am not sure I understand fully this answer.

Comment: Number $1$ is not allowed here.

Comment: Any number can be expressed as sum of powers of $2$. That just finishes the problem since you can express any prime in terms of $2$.

Comment: Where is number $1$?

Comment: For odd numbers you could use one $3$ and the rest powers of $2$ (and then you wouldn't have to use $1$).

Comment: @Haran $2^0=1$ in your $79$ example.

Comment: Oh that $1$. Yeah exactly.